# Add (optional) synopsis for a topic

Tags: feature-request, documentation

## TL;DR

Let us add a synopsis/single sentence that describes the topic.

## Motivation

Have a look at the [Traversable](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/754/traversable#t=20160721105356053956) documentation for example. The very first (current example) starts like this:

> ## Traversable
>
> #### [An instance of Traversable for a binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/754/traversable/2559/an-instance-of-traversable-for-a-binary-tree#t=201607211120537105429)
>
> Implementations of `traverse` usually look like an implementation of
>   `fmap` in an `Applicative` context.
>
> ```
> data Tree a = Leaf
>             | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
>
> instance Traversable Tree where
>     traverse f Leaf = pure Leaf
>     traverse f (Node l x r) = Node <$> travserse f l <*> f x <*> traverse f r
> ```
>
> This implementation performs an [in-order
>   traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order) of
>   the tree.

Well, that's great. I still don't know what the hell `Traversable` or `traverse` is for, though. While that's an orthogonal problem, one could aleviate it if we were able to provide a short sentence in the topic:

> ## Traversable
>
> A typeclass that provides a way to traverse structures with effects
>
> #### [An instance of Traversable for a binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/754/traversable/2559/an-instance-of-traversable-for-a-binary-tree#t=201607211120537105429).
>
> ...

This also fits the `@brief description` usually found in (well-)documented code. A reader should immediately know that topic XYZ is the one they're looking after, and not a topic about the XYZLite variant.